# How to prevent switching threads in FOR loop, while using omp directive

Tags: multithreading, for-loop, openmp

Assume such  simple  FOR  loop

```
#pragma omp parallel for
 for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
 {
    //do_something_1
    //do_something_2
    //do_something_3
 }
```

As I understand, loop  iterations can ran in any order. This is fine for me. 
The problem is, that threads can switch between themselfs in the  middle  of iteration execution. 
Assume there where created 10 threads(as a number of iterations).
Lets say, thread_1 is currently running, and after completing  do_something_1  and do_something_2 lines, it switched to thread_4(for example). 
Is there a way to force a thread  to complete whole  iteration without being switched, I mean thread_1 completing lines do_something_1, do_something_2 and do_something_3 without being interrupted. 
I understand that this is a part of OS algorithm for multithreading  environment, but this hope there is a way to bypass it.

**Edit:**

Using ORDERED clause in pragma is needed only in 2 cases, 
1) You need a result of previous iteration in current iteration. And than it will be a single thread program
2) You need, that your index will be correct in each iteration(thought you still can run all iterations parallel).

Let's see example for my problem:

```
 int new_index = 0;

 #pragma omp parallel for
 for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
 {
    <mutex lock>          
    new_index++  
    <mutex unlock>


    //do_something_1
    //do_something_2
    //do_something_3
    my_array[new_index] = 5; //correct
    my_array[i] = 5; //not correct
 }
```

So, there will be still 10 iterations, but now it should be a correct index each time for my_array.
The problem is : thread_1 increments  new_index(new_index = 1), complete do_something_1, and then switched to  thread_2.
Thread_2 completes it's loop completely(new_index = 2), but now , when OS switch back to thread_1, there is no correct new_index(new_index = 1) and my_array stays unchanged. 
So, I thought if it possible to tall to OS, don't switch threads in a middle of iteration.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent this? What exactly do you mean with "switching to a thread"? A CPU/Core/HW-Thread may switch threads, but the iterations don't. I.e. the entire loop iteration will always be executed by the same OpenMP thread.

Comment: I need to run iterations in sequential order(behavior of algorithm), but don't want to use  ORDERED  clause  in pragma, because it will be a serious bottleneck, so I am trying  to make a trick with global counter inside a  LOOP, mutex lock  on this counter and creating  "new index" for LOOP, using this counter. But for the correct behavior, I need each iteration to be completed without being interrupted

Comment: Sorry, but this is not yet clear what your *actual dependency* is. Please try to create a [mcve] so we can actually see it in code. Right now you are basically saying *I want it to be ordered, but ordered is too bad for performance*...

Comment: Your latest example suggests that you  need to read up about the scope of variables in OpenMP, since what you seem to be saying is "I have  shared variable but I wanted a thread private one".